# OpenLayers 3: align/rotate labels with line features

Tags: text, openlayers-3, label

Is it possible to align/rotate text labels to a line feature?  For example, if a line runs southwest to northeast (45 degrees), then the text placement should also be 45 degrees?  Is this possible?  I did look through the OL documentation but couldn't find anything of this nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a label "follow" a line in OpenLayers 3, but you can rotate it.  See in this example: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html

Try setting the "Rotation" then hit the refresh button and you'll see the label being rendered on that angle.

If you use a style function, you could calculate the average angle of the line to determine the angle to render its label.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what suspected.  I'm otherwise super impressed with OL3!

Comment: You could also take a look at the ol3-ext library: http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.style.textpath.html

Comment: Thanks, Alexandre! I'm already using the ol3-ext LayerSwitcher and its awesome. Will look into its line labeling features.